# Any Linux command to see the URL of file a process is downloading?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

When a process is stuck in downloading a remote file(I can see from jstack that is is being blocked in socket read), is there any Linux command to tell what's the actual URL of the remote file that the process is downloading?

Tools like lsof seem only giving the remote host, instead of the path of particular remote files.

Comment: Yes, `httpry -i <your network interface>`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6281/373195.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the client has already sent the HTTP request to the server and is now waiting for the response the exact URL requested is no longer available on the network. Nor  is the URL available somewhere in sockets states because these deal only with network and transport layer information and not with application level information (i.e. HTTP). If you are lucky than you can find the original URL somewhere inside the memory of the application but since it is actually not needed any longer by the application (request has been sent) it might be, that it is not even known to the application any longer.